# Firefox Restclient plugin import fails

Tags: firefox-addon, rest-client

I am trying to use Firefox Restclient plugin to post some REST calls. This already works.

But now I need to execute my requests from another machine. 
I wanted to export my requests and import them there but the import keeps failing.

What I already tried:

`-firefox57` with latest plugin version - import does not work, no response

`-using firefox56` with `plugin2.05` - message that import succeeded, but I can not open `manage Favourites` section and I see the requests nowhere

does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Apparently I tried the above described while there was a bug in the REST plugin. this bug is now fixed and I can import the exported requests with firefox57

Comment: Since I am new to StackOverflow I am not sure how to proceed now; whether I am supposed to mark the question as resolved, or post my comment as an aswer. In case I am doing wrong please tell me how to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

A certain time after successful import, still you will be not able to see the favourite due to access restrictions, mostly in Linux machine. You can see a pop for access while saving another rest for access, allow it it will fetch all.